# What is the best practice for loading data into BigQuery table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Currently I'm loading data from `Google Storage` to `stage_table_orders` using `WRITE_APPEND`. Since this load both new and existed order  there could be a case where same order has more than one version the field `etl_timestamp` tells which row is the most updated one.

then I `WRITE_TRUNCATE` my `production_table_orders` with query like:

```
select ...
from (
    SELECT  * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY date_purchased, orderid order by etl_timestamp DESC) as rn 
    FROM `warehouse.stage_table_orders` )
where rn=1
```

Then the `production_table_orders` always contains the most updated version of each order.

This process is suppose to run **every 3 minutes**.

I'm wondering if this is the best practice.
I have around 20M rows. It seems not smart to `WRITE_TRUNCATE` 20M rows every 3 minutes.

Suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are doing the same. To help improve performance though, try to partition the table by `date_purchased` and cluster by `orderid`.
Use a CTAS statement (to the table itself) as you cannot add partition after fact.

> EDIT: use 2 tables and MERGE

Depending on your particular use case i.e. the number of fields that could be updated between old and new, you could use 2 tables, e.g. `stage_table_orders` for the imported records and `final_table_orders` as destination table and do
a `MERGE` like so:

```
MERGE final_table_orders F
USING stage_table_orders S
ON F.orderid = S.orderid AND
   F.date_purchased = S.date_purchased
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET field_that_change = S.field_that_change
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (field1, field2, ...) VALUES(S.field1, S.field2, ...)
```

**Pro**: efficient if few rows are "upserted", not millions (although not tested) + pruning partitions *should* work.

**Con**: you have to explicitly list the fields in the update and insert clauses. A one-time effort if schema is pretty much fixed.

There are may ways to de-duplicate and there is no one-size-fits-all. Search in SO for similar requests using `ARRAY_AGG`, or `EXISTS` with `DELETE` or `UNION ALL`,... Try them out and see which performs better for YOUR dataset.

Comment: Are you doing it every 5 minutes? Doesn't it cause a huge billing from Google?

Comment: Not more than your current solution, and probably less thanks to pruning. Did you try ? I added an alternative.